# Неправильное поведение программы (Java)

Tags: java

Описание проблемы скорее будет понятнее представленным кодом:

```
package com.company;

class Box {

    double widht;
    double heidht;
    double depth;

    //---сконструировать клон объекта
    Box (Box ob){ //-передать объект
        widht = ob.widht;
        heidht = ob.heidht;
        depth = ob.depth;
    }

    //---констуктор, применяемый при указании всех размеров
    Box (double w, double h, double d){
        widht = w;
        heidht = h;
        depth = d;
    }

    //---конструктор при отсутствии размеров
    Box(){
        widht = -1;
        heidht = -1;
        depth = -1;
    }

    //---констуктор для куба
    Box (double len){

        widht = heidht = depth = len;
    }

    //---посчитать и вернуть объем
    double volume (){
        return widht * heidht * depth;
    }
}

class BoxWeight extends Box{

    double weight; //---вес объекта

    //---констуктор
    BoxWeight(double w, double h, double d, double m){
        weight = w;
        heidht = h;
        depth = d;
        weight = m;
    }
}

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BoxWeight myBox1 = new BoxWeight(10, 20, 15, 34.3);
        BoxWeight myBox2 = new BoxWeight(2, 3, 4, 0.076);

        double vol;

        vol = myBox1.volume();
        System.out.println("Объем myBox1 = " + vol);
        System.out.println("Вес myBox1 = " + myBox1.weight);
        System.out.println();

        vol = myBox2.volume();
        System.out.println("Объем myBox2 = " + vol);
        System.out.println("Вес myBox2 = " + myBox2.weight);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Выполнение кода дает результат:**

Объем myBox1 = -300.0
Вес myBox1 = 34.3

Объем myBox2 = -12.0
Вес myBox2 = 0.076

**А должен дать такой:**

Объем myBox1 = **3000.0**
Вес myBox1 = 34.3

Объем myBox2 = **24.0**
Вес myBox2 = 0.076

Не понимаю в чем загвоздка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка тут:

```
BoxWeight(double w, double h, double d, double m){
    weight = w;
    heidht = h;
    depth = d;
    weight = m;
}
```

В первой строке вместо widht вы присваиваете в weight.

P.S. heidht правильно height, widht правильно width

Comment: Спасибо) и за англ. отдельное)